# If greater than multiply by result, if not don't

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to do an if else statement, if the results of the index query is greater than the other. I want it to go like this:

If index query / index query's result is greater than 1, multiply the formula by the percentage it is greater than 1.

For example

If 10 / 5 is greater than 1, multiply it by the sum of (4 * 3), else, don't multiply it and just do the sum.

```
=IF(
    INDEX(AK:AK,MATCH($A3,M:M,0))>INDEX(AL:AL,MATCH($A4,M:M,0)),
    SUM(B12*E13*R24)*(INDEX(AK:AK,MATCH($A3,M:M,0),SUM(B12*E13*R24)))
    )
```

not getting anywhere with this.

Comment: `SUM(B12*E13*R24)` is just one number, did you mean `SUM(B12, E13, R24)`?

Comment: Yeah I'd want it to be multiplied by just that one number.

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected results

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/ea71477c5f800a9a6003c846e19991fa.png

I want the =SUM(B12*E13*R22) and then if the HPPG in AK is greater than the APPG in AL, to multiply it by the percentage it is greater than.

Comment: But there's no point in writing `=SUM(B12*E13*R22)` - there is only one value to sum up. You can use just `=(B12*E13*R22)` and you'll get the same in this part.

Comment: So you explained the workflow for when the HPPG is greater than APPG but what should happen if 1) they are equal 2) HPPG < APPG

Comment: Ah okay, thanks, still learning

Comment: @chancea HPPG < APPG then just do the (B12*E13*R24) ignore the previous multiplier, the same for if they are even

Comment: I'm unclear on *'to multiply it by the percentage it is greater than 1'*. If 6/4 then multiply by 1.5 or 0.5?

Comment: In that case, see my answer below. Add a comment explaining the desired outcome on *no match* if you need some judicious error control with the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this can be reduced down to multiplying your base calculation by either *1* or the quotient of the two lookups when their quotient is greater than *1*.

```
=B12*E13*R24*MAX(INDEX(AK:AK,MATCH($A3,M:M,0))/INDEX(AL:AL,MATCH($A4,M:M,0)), 1)
```

Comment: Does the max statement mean that if its greater?

Comment: It is the maximum of INDEX ÷ INDEX or 1. If your two lookups divided by each other are greater than 1, multiply by the two lookups divided by each other. Otherwise multiply by 1 (e.g. do not change the value). If 6/4 multiply by 6/4. If 4/6 then multiply by 1.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot Jeeped. As an aside, due you recommend anywhere to learn these things, or is it just sort of learning through doing?

Comment: Designing this formula was broken down into two part. a) recognizing the math principle that multiplying by *1* does not change the original number b) knowing that a [MAX function](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/max-function-f7bec1eb-9c66-489a-9166-51d2c9d19333) exists within Excel's repetoire of worksheet functions. The latter comes from experience although a review of [Excel functions (by category)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-functions-by-category-5F91F4E9-7B42-46D2-9BD1-63F26A86C0EB) can be quite enlightening.